# mysql dataset with timestamp interval

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mariadb

I have a dataset with timestamps and values like this:

```
Timestamp            Value
"01-01-2017 09:01" , "900"
"01-01-2017 09:28" , "770"
"01-01-2017 09:55" , "240"
"01-01-2017 10:36" , "850"
"01-01-2017 11:01" , "820"
```

But what happens is that there is not always a measurement within 30 minutes, and I want to 'fill' this in with an extra row with null for value.
Something like this:

```
Timestamp            Value
"01-01-2017 09:01" , "900"
"01-01-2017 09:28" , "770"
"01-01-2017 09:55" , "240"
"01-01-2017 10:00" , null     <--
"01-01-2017 10:36" , "850"
"01-01-2017 11:01" , "820"
```

How can I do this?

I'm using a Google Graphs line-graph with the 'function' parameter to make the line curve. When there is a gap in my measurements (=dataset) it should also show in the graph. Now it just connects all the dots to make a smooth line, so I need to add entries (timestamps) with a null value to create these gaps.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stR8p.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how does that value fix anything?  There is still a 36 minute gap to the next record.

Comment: I'm using Google Graphs to draw a curved line chart. If there is a null value within that missing time frame, the chart will be interrupted. And that is what I want.

Comment: how this value came?

Comment: This looks like case of XY problem. Please clearly state your original problem and you should have better answers to solve that. See: The [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I would like the data to be added to the select statement, so no inserts in the database.